# Getting several node values using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So lets say you have the following XML-structure.

```
 <Class>
  <Students>
    <Student>
      <StudentNo>555</StudentNo>
      <Firstname>Joe</Firstname>
      <Lastname>Smith</Lastname>
    </Student>
     <Student>
      <StudentNo>222</StudentNo>
      <Firstname>Smith</Firstname>
      <Lastname>Joe</Lastname>
    </Student>
  <Students>
</Class>
```

And you would like to get all the Firstnames and lastnames using linq. For now I got the following

```
foreach (XElement x in data.Descendants("Student").SelectMany(e => data.Descendants("Firstname")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
            }
```

But how could i get lastName as well?

Comment: Your example XML has numerous errors, to make it easier for people to answer your question you should post a working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using an anonymous type:

```
var query=data.Descendants("Student")
              .Select(s=> new { FirstName=s.Element("FirstName").Value,
                                LastName=s.Element("Lastname").Value});
```

Or you can create a custom class and save the result:

```
var query=data.Descendants("Student")
              .Select(s=> new Student{ FirstName=s.Element("FirstName").Value,
                                       LastName=s.Element("Lastname").Value});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write this like:

```
var firstnames = data.Descendants("Student").Select(x => x.Firstname);
var lastnames = data.Descendants("Student").Select(x => x.Lastname);
```

Or

```
var firstAndLastnames = data.Descendants("Student").Select(x => new { Firstname = x.Firstname, Lastname = x.Lastname });
```